# SQL Server Dynamic Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, pivot, crosstab

Hello I have a table that contains employee punch in and punch out data from a timekeeping system. I am looking to dynamically pivot the punch data column and total an employees shift span. However I am having issues with the dynamic pivot. I have checked a couple other posts, but I don't seem to be getting anywhere.

Here is the code:

```
USE wfcdb
DECLARE @cols as NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT  DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),EVENTDTM,101)) as DATE FROM TIMESHEETITEM  WHERE DATEDIFF(d,EVENTDTM,GetDate()) <7 ORDER BY DATE DESC
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                        ,1,1,'')

Set @query='SELECT EEID, ' + @cols + 'FROM (
SELECT p.PERSONnum as EEID,p.FULLNM as FULLNM, 
convert(varchar(10),ti.EVENTDTM,101) as PunchDate,
DATEDIFF(MINUTE,ti.enddtm,ti.startdtm)/60*-1 AS SPAN
FROM  (((((  
    TIMESHEETITEM ti  With (NoLock) LEFT JOIN  
        PUNCHEVENT pe With (NoLock) ON ti.STARTPUNCHEVENTID = pe.PUNCHEVENTID) LEFT JOIN 
            DATASOURCE ds ON pe.DATASOURCEID = ds.DATASOURCEID) LEFT JOIN 
                CLIENTCONTEXT cc ON ds.CLIENTCONTEXTID = cc.CLIENTCONTEXTID) 
    LEFT JOIN       PUNCHEVENT AS pe1  With (NoLock) ON ti.ENDPUNCHEVENTID = pe1.PUNCHEVENTID) LEFT JOIN 
            DATASOURCE AS ds1 ON pe1.DATASOURCEID = ds1.DATASOURCEID) LEFT JOIN 
                CLIENTCONTEXT AS cc1 ON ds1.CLIENTCONTEXTID = cc1.CLIENTCONTEXTID
    INNER JOIN PERSON p ON ti.EMPLOYEEID = p.PERSONID
    INNER JOIN LABORACCT la1 ON la1.laboracctid = ti.laboracctid
WHERE DATEDIFF(d,ti.EVENTDTM,GetDate()) <7
AND ti.TmShtItemTypeID = 40 
AND (isnull(cc.CLNT,'') + isnull(cc1.CLNT,''))<> '') X
PIVOT
(
    SUM(SPAN) 
    FOR PunchDate in (' + @cols + ')
    ) p'

Execute(@query)
```

And Here is the error message I receive:

> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ') X
>       PIVOT
>       (..... ) p'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
>   Incorrect syntax near ') X
>       PIVOT (.....

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to change this line: `AND (isnull(cc.CLNT,'') + isnull(cc1.CLNT,''))<> '') X`, with this one:`AND (isnull(cc.CLNT,'''') + isnull(cc1.CLNT,''''))<> '''') X`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are concatenating empty strings in your dynamic SQL you need to add a few more single quotes:

```
AND (isnull(cc.CLNT,'''') + isnull(cc1.CLNT,''''))<> '''') X
```

So the full code will be:

```
DECLARE @cols as NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT  DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),EVENTDTM,101)) as DATE 
                        FROM TIMESHEETITEM  WHERE DATEDIFF(d,EVENTDTM,GetDate()) <7 ORDER BY DATE DESC
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                        ,1,1,'')

Set @query='SELECT EEID, ' + @cols + 'FROM (
SELECT p.PERSONnum as EEID,p.FULLNM as FULLNM, 
convert(varchar(10),ti.EVENTDTM,101) as PunchDate,
DATEDIFF(MINUTE,ti.enddtm,ti.startdtm)/60*-1 AS SPAN
FROM  (((((  
    TIMESHEETITEM ti  With (NoLock) LEFT JOIN  
        PUNCHEVENT pe With (NoLock) ON ti.STARTPUNCHEVENTID = pe.PUNCHEVENTID) LEFT JOIN 
            DATASOURCE ds ON pe.DATASOURCEID = ds.DATASOURCEID) LEFT JOIN 
                CLIENTCONTEXT cc ON ds.CLIENTCONTEXTID = cc.CLIENTCONTEXTID) 
    LEFT JOIN       PUNCHEVENT AS pe1  With (NoLock) ON ti.ENDPUNCHEVENTID = pe1.PUNCHEVENTID) LEFT JOIN 
            DATASOURCE AS ds1 ON pe1.DATASOURCEID = ds1.DATASOURCEID) LEFT JOIN 
                CLIENTCONTEXT AS cc1 ON ds1.CLIENTCONTEXTID = cc1.CLIENTCONTEXTID
    INNER JOIN PERSON p ON ti.EMPLOYEEID = p.PERSONID
    INNER JOIN LABORACCT la1 ON la1.laboracctid = ti.laboracctid
WHERE DATEDIFF(d,ti.EVENTDTM,GetDate()) <7
AND ti.TmShtItemTypeID = 40 
AND (isnull(cc.CLNT,'''') + isnull(cc1.CLNT,''''))<> '''') X
PIVOT
(
    SUM(SPAN) 
    FOR PunchDate in (' + @cols + ')
    ) p'

execute @query
```

Comment: Brilliant, can't believe I missed it. Thanks

Comment: @user2551567 It is an easy miss.  One way to catch these bugs is to `print @query` and then paste the result in SSMS you will find the issues when dealing with dynamic SQL